# Validate an image in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using GD to create jpegs from files that a user uploads.

What is the best way to validate that the image the user has uploaded is valid?

By valid I mean that the file is not a corrupt image that GD won't like, I do extension testing client side so they can only upload jpegs/gifs/pngs.

Thanks

Comment: Pass the image (as a string) to `imagecreatefromstring` and see if it returns `FALSE` or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [getimagesize](http://php.net/getimagesize). It will return `FALSE` if the image could not be loaded. It has support for most image types.

Answer (score 0):

`getImageSize` would be your best choice but, be careful, if the file results are not valid you will get a warning. Using `@` before built in `imagesize` function will be ideal.